# Usar o grunt watch em diferentes diretórios dentro do mesmo projeto e ao mesmo tempo

Tags: grunt

Fala Galera.

Não sou um expert em Grunt, mas me viro e atualmente trabalho com o grunt funcionando numa estrutura mais convencional, onde os arquivos de mesma extensão ficam na mesma pasta, por exemplo: ".scss" dentro da pasta **assets/sass**, ".js" na **assets/js** e assim por diante.

Mas agora surgiu a necessidade de trabalhar com diversos subdiretórios dentro do mesmo projeto e gostaria de continuar usando o mesmo Gruntfile.js e os mesmos módulos instalados. Por exemplo:

```
projeto
--**src**
----node_modules
----Gruntfile.js
----package.json
--subprojetos
----**subprojeto-1**
------assets/css
--------*.css
--------*.scss
----**subprojeto-2**
------assets/css
--------*.css
--------*.scss
----**subprojeto-3**
------assets/css
--------*.css
--------*.scss
```

Essa minha dúvida acho que serve para outros plugins, mas uso especificamente o e grunt-contrib-sass e e grunt-contrib-watch.

Alguém já trabalhou desta forma antes e tem um caminho pra indicar ou seria necessário mesmo ter pacotes de instalação para cada subdiretório?

Comment: Já tentou usar o caminho '../subprojetos/assets/css' ?